# Apache Maven: "Failed to execute goal" error

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error

I'm new to Apache and Java in general (I'm used to C# with Visual Studio but my school's making me use Java with Apache). I'm trying to run a project, but every time I do, I get the following error:

`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project SortingProject: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]`

No solutions on here have worked so far but here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.sortingproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>SortingProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.sortingproject.SortingProject</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: There could be various reasons for this. Add '-X' at mvn command to show the complete log why it is failing. Additionally, the exec plugin is used to invoke additional executable, Java classes can also be executed by exec but it must be available at classpath. You can refer exec documentation to run Java classes: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html

Comment: You can try running from command like like: mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.sortingproject.SortingProject"